# Is there any aggregation contains all the relationships between things?

Tags: relations

We know there have many relationships between things, such as `causal relationship`, `parallel relationship` and so on.

But is there any books or post which describe all the relationship between things?

Comment: [Types of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_(philosophy)#Overview).

Comment: there only has Internal and External relationships, do not have practical relationship collection like `causal relationship`.

Comment: "The three types are (1) spatial relations, which include geometry and number, (2) relations of cause and effect, and (3) the classificatory relations of similarity and difference that underlie knowledge."